# MERN stack, Node api GET is getting served by browser as react request

Tags: node.js, express, react-redux, service-worker, mern

I am using MERN stack,

To Integrate login with facebook I have used facebook passport.

I have one endpoint to start facebook login flow: http://localhost:5000/api/auth/facebook

I have generated react build and served with express with express.static function.

Issue:
When I call the endpoint http://localhost:5000/api/auth/facebook with postment it works as it should.

When I put this url in the browser then it works like react app route request and page not found is displayed from react app.

Comment: your express routing should contain something like `app.get('/', (req, res) => res.render('index'))`, put this instruction after the one about `api/`

Comment: @Hitmands thanks for your comment everything is configured correctly the issue is service working is serving api call from local cache.

Comment: @yogs it's very hard to know what the issue is if we don't see how your server is configured in the js. Could you please add your server.js file or at least the parts where the configuration is made and the routing is handled? It would also be of great help if you provide the `package.json` to see which versions you have, and which libraries you have available.